# Trying to understand the struct HkdfLabel from tls1.3 RFC8446

Tags: tls

I'm looking at [RFC 8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-7.1) section 7.1 and trying to understand the following:

```
HKDF-Expand-Label(Secret, Label, Context, Length) =
            HKDF-Expand(Secret, HkdfLabel, Length)

       Where HkdfLabel is specified as:

       struct {
           uint16 length = Length;
           opaque label<7..255> = "tls13 " + Label;
           opaque context<0..255> = Context;
       } HkdfLabel;

       Derive-Secret(Secret, Label, Messages) =
            HKDF-Expand-Label(Secret, Label,
                              Transcript-Hash(Messages), Hash.length)
```

`HkdfLabel` appears to be a concatenation of a few fields, to make it "fit" into the signature of `Hkdf.Expand(...)`.  A few things I'm unclear on:

- Are the pieces that make up the struct of `HkdfLabel` expected to be concatenated in the order they're defined? e.g. `length||label||context`
- `length` = the hash length in bytes?
- the first `0..6` bits of `label` are not specified, assuming 0?
- `"tls13 " + Label` may be more or less bits than `7..255` allows for the assignment to `label`.  Is the expectation that it's zeroes if not long enough, or truncated to 256 bits if too long?
- same basic uncertainty around `context`, is the idea that `context` will always be exactly 256 bits?
- Assuming the above is correct, does that mean `HkdfLabel` will always be exactly 528 bits?

  - `HkdfLabel = hashLength<0..15>||label<0..255>||context<0..255>`

Comment: The RFC should be self-explaining. Your questions are not exactly fitting our scope. Here the implementation from [BoringSSL](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/ssl/test/runner/prf.go) that may help your cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3) explains the data structures and their representation as octet strings (or byte strings: this RFC uses “octet” and “byte” interchangeably). See in particular [§3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.1):

> Multiple-byte data items are concatenations of bytes, from left to right, from top to bottom.

An `HkdfLabel` is the concatenation of 2 bytes for `length` (big-endian, see [§3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.3)), 7 to 255 bytes for `label`, and 0 to 255 bytes for `context`. [§3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-3.4) explains the notation `<7..255>` it means between 7 and 255 bytes inclusive. The length of the `HkdfLabel` can therefore be anywhere from 9 to 514 bytes.

The `length` field in the `HkdfLabel` returned by `HKDF-Expand-Label` is the value that was passed as the `Length` argument. When it's called from `Derived-Secret`, this is the length of the hash in bytes (not bits) ([§7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-7.1): “Hash.length is its output length in bytes”).

The first 6 bytes of `label` are `74 6c 73 31 33 20`, the ASCII encoding of `"tls13 "` ([§7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-7.1): “The labels specified in this document are all ASCII strings”).

`"tls13 " + Label` is the concatenation of a 6-byte string with `Label`. Since the result must be at least 7 bytes long, this effectively forbids empty labels, which I can't find stated explicitly anywhere. There is no padding or truncation. Note that once again, these are lengths in bytes (octets), not bits. The label must also be at most 249 bytes long to fit.

`Context` can be anywhere from 0 to 255 bytes

Comment: Nit: `opaque <7..255>` means 7 to 255 bytes of data preceded by a one-byte length field, and similarly for `0..255`